# Setting up Firebird for remote Access with JDBC

Tags: java, database, jdbc, ubuntu, firebird

I have installed Firebird 2.5 on my Ubuntu 10.10 server for some testing. However somewhere I have gone wrong, I am looking for the way in which I create a new 'superuser' (equivalent), create a new database and then finally what I need to call on to connect using JDBC. I know with MySQL and PostgreSQL you have to modify config files to allow remote access, is firebird the same?

I have tried CREATE USER... and DATABASE. Neither have worked so I guess I have missed somthing. Any advice for what should be a straight forward database and remote connection.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new database: http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg25-databases.html

Adding new users and configuring the databases: http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg25-config.html

User configuration and passwords: http://www.volny.cz/iprenosil/interbase/ip_ib_isc4.htm

Troubleshooting connection issues: http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=doc&sub=contrib&id=connect_to_linux

(All links taken from the Firebird documentation index: http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=doc)

Answer (score -1):

I had se same problem with Firebird 3.0 but I don't if the way to solve it is the same for Firebird 2.5

You need to set up some parameters in the firebird.conf file. These parameters are the Wire encryption and the authentication methods for the java driver.

[These](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/wiki/Jaybird-and-Firebird-3) steps worked for me.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.